# How to show the sum from $\sum_{k=0}^ \infty((r^k)/(k!))$ converges absolutely for any $r\in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

How to show the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{r^k}{k!}$ converges absolutely for any $r\in \mathbb R$

How should I go about doing this bizarre question I came across? Looking for some help!

Comment: Doesn't this just say that $e^x$ is everywhere-analytic?

Comment: Since this is sort of a standard exercise, you might try to explain where you get stuck.

Comment: I guess what I get stuck on is that I attempt to evaluate the limit as $k$ approaches infinity of $a_k+1/a_k$ and get $0$. But that doesn't mean that it's absolutely convergent, does it?

Answer (score 1):

A more elementary approach:

Let $a_k = \dfrac{r^k}{k!}$.
$\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}
=\dfrac{\frac{r^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{r^k}{k!}}
=\dfrac{r}{k+1}
$.
Therefore,
if $k > 2r$,
$\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}
< \dfrac12
$.
By induction,
for $k > 2r$
and
$m \ge 1$,
$\dfrac{a_{k+m}}{a_k}
< \dfrac1{2^m}
$.

At this point,
we are essentially done,
because this result says that
for large enough $k$,
$a_k$ decreases like
a geometric series,
and the sum of that series
converges absolutely.
The rest of this answer
fills in the details.

Since the max value of
$a_k$
is about when $k = [r]$,
$a_k
<\dfrac{r^{[r]}}{[r]!}
=amax(r)
$.

Therefore,
for $k > 2r$
and
$m \ge 1$,
$a_{k+m}
<\dfrac{a_k}{2^m}
<\dfrac{amax(r)}{2^m}
$.

Therefore
$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{2[r]+2+m}
<\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{amax(r)}{2^m}
< amax(r)
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_{m}
&=\sum_{m=0}^{2[r]+2} a_{m}+\sum_{m=2[r]+3}^{\infty} a_{m}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{2[r]+2} a_{m}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{2[r]+2+m}\\
&< (2[r]+3)amax(r)+amax(r)\\
&= (2[r]+4)amax(r)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
the sum has a computable bound
that depends only of $r$,
so the sum converges absolutely
for any $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Radius of convergence for the exponential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281961/radius-of-convergence-for-the-exponential-function) and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: I don't find this very helpful. This is a different question entirely. Perhaps it is the same function but the details about the question don't aid in answering this one.

Comment: Then check the Wikipedia link. It gives the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

To show it's absolutely convergent enough to check the series $\sum\frac{r^k}{k!}$ for $r>0$

Now $u_k=\frac{r^k}{k!}$

lim $\frac{u_{k+1}}{u_{k}}=0<1$

Hence converges

Comment: But how to show that it converges absolutely?

Comment: Please see my answer.